# Moving the position cursor to the end of string in edit box

Tags: delphi

After reassigning a string to an edit box, the position cursor is moved to the before the first character in the string. How do I set the position cursor to the end of the string? This is my current code:

```
begin
  pin:=ledtAdminPin.Text;
  SetLength(pin, 4);
  ledtAdminPin.Text:=pin;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`SelStart`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.SelStart) property:

```
ledtAdminPin.SelStart := high(Integer);
```

Comment: `SelLength := 0` should do it, I think

Comment: Strange thing is, it should.... but it isn't. The code is being run during the OnShow event of the form, and even by running the `SelLength := 0` in this event, it doesn't seem to deselect the text.

Comment: Works for me here. You must have something extra that I cannot see.

Comment: Do you have `AutoSelect` enabled on your edit control. That can screw with manual selection.

Comment: I would use `SelStart := ledtAdminPin.GetTextLen` instead of `SelStart := MaxInt`.  But if `MaxInt` works, so be it.